# SSRS Health Check

Tags: reporting-services

We are building reporting functionality into our web application. What is the easiest way of determining of if the ReportServer is up and running. I was thinking of just calling the ListChildren method, but I was wondering if anyone had any other ideas.

If for some reason the Reporting Server was down, I would hide the reporting functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best thing to do would be check the reporting services service is running, or do a simple http call to web site to make sure you dont return a 500/404 etc error